# how to change text color of <p:watermark>

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

In my jSF 2.0-PrimeFaces application I am using  component and I need to change the color of the text in the  component.

The sample can be found at [here](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/watermark.jsf)

how to change text color of  JSF 2-PrimeFaces component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From primefaces documentation:

`There’s only one css style class applying watermark which is ‘.ui-watermark’, you can override this
class to bring in your own style. Note that this style class is not applied when watermark uses html5
placeholder if available.`

PrimeFaces Userʼs Guide page:433
Primefaces uses jquery's watermark. Check [here](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-watermark/) for more information.

**try this:**

```
  input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
          color: red !important;
       }
```

**Note**: That the above only works in some browsers as mentioned in the link. I tested it on `chrome` and `IE7`, it is working in `Google Chrome` but not in `Internet Explorer`

Comment: .ui-watermark {
    color: red !important;
    font-size: 0.5em;
}

Comment: as mentioned in the answer, it is working on chrome, rockmelt but not on IE.